# I am not able to curve a plane using array and curve modifier using a curve

Tags: modeling

I used a curve and plane and created a path curve and arrayed the plane then added a curve modifier and when edit the curve to curve it distorts the whole mesh of plane.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but can't udnerstand what you need. But if you wan't to distort the plane along the curve you must subdivide it. Press Tab to enter Edit mode and right click and choose subdivide.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're looking for, the distortion is calculated at each vertex/edge of the plane:

[image]

In the image above, both curves are the same size and both planes are the same size but the plane on the left only has the one edge in the middle.  So the beginning of the plane is distorted to the curve, the end of the plane is distorted to the curve, and the one edge in the middle is distorted to the curve.  I created the plane on the right by going into edit mode, pressing Ctrl-R to subdivide, and using the mouse wheel to add several more edges.  Since each edge is distorted to the curve, the more edges you have, the closer your plane will follow the curve.  Hope that helps!